# want to create two label in tkinter gui window and display continous counting value:

Tags: python-2.7, variables, tkinter

i have written a code for that its working and window popped up with two label but values are not incremented::i am quite new to python ,please help me out to resolve ...
thanks in advance..

```
import Tkinter
import time
root = Tkinter.Tk()
var  = Tkinter.IntVar()
var1 = Tkinter.IntVar()
label1 = Tkinter.Label(root, textvariable=var)
label2 = Tkinter.Label(root, textvariable=var1)
root.geometry("200x200")
label1.pack()
label2.pack()
def function():
    while 1:
        i=0
        j=0
        i += 1
        var.set(i)
        #time.sleep(1)
        var1.set(j)
        j += 1
        root.update()
        #time.sleep(1)

root.after(10, function)
root.update()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want your counters to be automatically incremented as time goes by? If yes, the easiest solution is to reuse the `after` method at the end of your `function()`:

```
import Tkinter as tk

def function():
    var1.set(var1.get()+1)
    var2.set(var2.get()+1)
    root.after(100, function)

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
var1 = tk.IntVar()
var2 = tk.IntVar()
label1 = tk.Label(root, textvariable=var1)
label2 = tk.Label(root, textvariable=var2)
label1.pack()
label2.pack()
root.after(10, function)
root.mainloop()
```